# Combine multiple select queries from one table into a single statement used for exporting to a file while containing unique values between each select

Tags: sql-server, select

This task that I'm working on is melting my brain a little bit. I'm trying to apply 18 types of select statements each containing specific conditions to get a combined list of accounts to use in an export file. Wondering if it is possible to apply numerous amount of select statements against a single table and select only unique values.

I'm trying to get it so my select statement for conditions row 2 and so forth do not contain accounts that exist in the previous condition statements.

For example... my list looks like this:

```
1.  3K accounts that are delinquent with BadPhones as Primary.
2.  3K accounts that are delinquent with BadPhones as Secondary.
3.  3K accounts that are delinquent with BadPhones as ANI.
4.  3K accounts that are current with BadPhones as Primary.
5.  3K accounts that are current with BadPhones as Secondary.
6.  3K accounts that are current with BadPhones as ANI.
7.  3K accounts that are delinquent with WrongPhones as Primary.
8.  3K accounts that are delinquent with WrongPhones as Secondary.
9.  3K accounts that are delinquent with WrongPhones as ANI.
10. 3K accounts that are current with WrongPhones as Primary.
11. 3K accounts that are current with WrongPhones as Secondary.
12. 3K accounts that are current with WrongPhones as ANI.
13. 3K accounts that are delinquent with Good Phones as Primary.
14. 3K accounts that are delinquent with Good Phones as Secondary.
15. 3K accounts that are delinquent with Good Phones as ANI.
16. 3K accounts that are current with Good Phones as Primary.
17. 3K accounts that are current with Good Phones as Secondary.
18. 3K accounts that are current with Good Phones as ANI.
```

And my query to select all the accounts for the file would look like this:

```
SELECT
a.AccountCode as AccountInformation,
c.LastName InputConsumerLastName,
c.FirstName as InputConsumerFirstName,
LEFT(c.MiddleName,1) as InputConsumerMiddleInitial,
s.Suffix as InputConsumerSuffix,
ad.AddressLine1 as InputStreetAddress,
ad.AddressLine2 as InputStreetAddress2,
ad.City as InputCity,
st.StateCode as InputState,
ad.ZipCode as InputZip,
ad.ZipCode4 as InputZip4,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) as ScrubDate,
p.cp_PhoneNumber as PhoneNumber
FROM
Account a
LEFT JOIN Customer c on a.XID =c.AccountXID
LEFT JOIN Suffix s on c.SuffixXID=s.XID
LEFT JOIN AccountAddress aa on a.XID=aa.AccountXID
LEFT JOIN Address ad on aa.AddressXID=ad.XID 
LEFT JOIN State st on ad.StateXID=st.XID
LEFT JOIN AccountPhone ap on a.XID=ap.AccountXID
LEFT JOIN Phone p on ap.PhoneXID=p.XID
WHERE aa.AddressTypeXID=1
AND ISNUMERIC(p.cp_PhoneNumber)=1
AND p.cp_PhoneNumber!='3201111111'
AND ISNUMERIC(p.AreaCode)=1
AND CAST(AreaCode as int)>=200
```

But I need to select the 3K samples each meeting their own conditions and then compile it all into a single select without having duplicate AccountCode.

I'm not worried about the specific where conditions to be applied to each type of select. My concern is selecting the total amount of 54K unique accounts containing each of the 18 conditions that select 3K accounts to total the 54K unique accounts.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The complexity of this problem is far beyond what SQL is designed for. What if the "first" batch randomly picks all the matches for the "second" batch (that can no longer be met), yet a different set matching the first criteria does exist? You probably need to rethink your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temp table. Add an index on the AccountCode column in the temp table. Insert "TOP 3,000" into the temp table for the first select. For subsequent selects, use a "where not exists" checking to make sure the AcccountCode is not already represented in the temp table. Finally, export your 54k rows from the temp table.

Comment: I'm going to try using this approach.